# Express request processing timeout?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, http, express

I have a small API that runs child process on request and responds with it's final output. Processing may take up to 5-10-30 minutes and it's okay. However Express drops connection after some time and logs
`POST /api/v1/check - - ms - -` and even though child process' output is still getting processed it's never returned to a client.

Requests are made with jQuery.

How can I make this work properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably the browser that is timing out the connection.  You can set a timeout value client side when making the ajax request with jQuery.

The jQuery `timeout` argument as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) can be set to a time of your choosing.

There are also methods by which a server can dribble small pieces of a dummy response back (before the actual response) to cause the browser to not timeout the connection, but in this case if you control the client, it is easier to just change its timeout value.

Server-side, you can control when an incoming connection would timeout by setting the timeout value on the server.  That is described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback) in the doc for the `http` module.

Comment: Thank you, your answers has helped me too.

Comment: None of this seems to work for my particular case, but thanks anyway, very useful!

Comment: @fivepointseven - Why doesn't it work for you?  If you set both client and server timeouts appropriately, you should be able to control it.

Comment: @jfriend00 right, but for some reason express still logs `- - ms - -` in a few minutes and response is processed but never sent to client. Anyway, I've changed the structure of the whole thing so that it's now starting worker with one request and checks for results (that are now stored in file) with another request every few seconds. I should probably implement something like socket.io for long lasting connections...